# Docker containers cannot connect through overlay networks

Tags: docker, vagrant, overlay, consul

I've got multiple hosts running Docker, I use Consul as the key-value store. I am able to create overlay networks, containers can see each other's hostname and IP, /etc/hosts is nicely updated when containers are created/destroyed. However, the containers that are on different hosts can't actually connect to each other (the ones on the same host can).

I've kept investigating logs, and Docker daemon logs contain these:

```
[INFO] serf: EventMemberJoin: vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64 192.168.57.103

[ERR] memberlist: Conflicting address for vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64. Mine: 192.168.57.103:7946 Theirs: 192.168.57.102:7946

[ERR] serf: Node name conflicts with another node at 192.168.57.102:7946. Names must be unique! (Resolution enabled: true)
```

Should the Docker daemons identify themselves somehow? It looks that Serf is confused because each daemon just uses the hostname as identifier.

Answer (score 6):

Answer: cluster members need to have unique hostnames, because Docker daemons are identified base on the hostname (by default). Why on Earth did Docker leave this out from their tutorials?

Comment: Can you please show where I can specify host names.

Comment: You should set the hostname property when starting the container (`-h` or `--hostname`).

Answer (score 3):

Check hostname for the machines on which docker is running. To check hostname run this on terminal.

```
hostname
```

It should be different for all nodes.